# Cant add 1 to variable?

Tags: python, if-statement, environment-variables

The below is from MIT CS course, lecture three, question three.

```
x = 10
i = 1
while(i<x):
    if x%i == 0:
       print 'divisor ',i
    i = i+1
```

I have managed to get the desired output using range but no matter how I format this example it either goes on displaying Division 1 or just hangs.

Comment: All numbers are divisible by 1

Comment: your code works fine

Comment: You get Divisor 1, Divisor 2, Divisor 5? Strange, I cant get it to work in Python 2.7 or 3.4 and tried moving things around. It won't count up i.

Comment: Must be spacing, Ill give it another go.

Comment: yep, make sure you are not mixing spaces and tabs...

Comment: Well I have no idea why but it works now. Must have been spacing, checking to see exactly what. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 10
i = 1
while(i<x):
    if x%i == 0:
       print 'divisor ',i
    i = i+1

divisor  1
divisor  2
divisor  5
```

The code works as expected. Check your indentation when you're running it yourself.

Comment: Since I am new no more pasting code in for a while. Thanks.